# SharePoint List - Yes or No Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem

I have a requirement with SharePoint List to have to option with Yes or No Column or a choice.
If the Choice is NO (Nothing to be done)

IF the Choice is Yes (then i need 3 options) like -

1. End of Day
2. High priority
3. Fill able Date (DD/MM/YYYY)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Need to get this done using out of box. In the new/edit form.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a Yes/No column "**YesNo**", and create three columns "**End of Day**","**High priority**" and "**Fill able Date**". Then add the code below into a script editor web part into new/edit form page.
If yes/no column choice "Yes", those three columns show, if choice "No", hide those columns.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var yesNoFieldName="YesNo";
    var optionFields=["End of Day","High priority","Fill able Date"];
    if($("input[title='"+yesNoFieldName+"']").is(':checked')){
        showFields(optionFields);
    }else{
        hideFields(optionFields);
    }
    $("input[title='"+yesNoFieldName+"']").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){         
            showFields(optionFields);
        }else{
            hideFields(optionFields);
        }
    });
})
function hideFields(optionFields){
    for(var i=0;i<optionFields.length;i++){
        $(".ms-standardheader:contains('"+optionFields[i]+"')").closest("tr").hide();
    }
}
function showFields(optionFields){
    for(var i=0;i<optionFields.length;i++){
        $(".ms-standardheader:contains('"+optionFields[i]+"')").closest("tr").show();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want some sort of validation based on yes/no check box and 'End of Day' and 'High Priority' are choices in a dropdown. If yes then you try below steps.

Create a yes/no column, a choice column with choices 'End of the Day', 'High Priority', a date column. Then navigate to list settings -> Validation settings and use below formula to ensure form performs validation at all times. In below formula 'YesNo' is a yesno column name, ChoiceCol is Choice column name and DateCol is date column name.

```
=IF(YesNo=TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(ChoiceCol),FALSE,IF(ISBLANK(DateCol),FALSE,TRUE)),TRUE)
```

The above formula invalidates the form if the Yes/No column is true and either the dropdown and date column is blank. You can always use field description field to provide explanation on when to use a particular field (as we are not showing/hiding any fields here)

Alternatively you can always use some javascript on the forms to perform validation and show/hide fields based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use a managed metadata column with options yes and no, and a branch with additional options under No.